# HTTPException in Laravel artisan route list

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-artisan

I am having a problem that running `php artisan route:list` is throwing a `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException` but it is not giving me any other output or logging it anywhere I can see.

I have tried `composer update` and `dump-autoload` as well as refreshing the route cache, debug is also set to true.
How can I get more information about the `HttpException` that is being thrown?

Comment: remove any service providers you have manually added in `config/app.php` (or `app/config/app.php` for Laravel 4) and try `route:list` again

Comment: Look for any typos in the config file.

Comment: I've tried removing custom service contains but hasn't helped wvwn with another composer dump-autoload and a route cache clear.

Comment: I've also looked in the config file but cannot see anything wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that you can run the route:list command with the -verbose flag which outputs the full error stack.

```
php artisan -v route:list
```

From this I then found my errors, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In my case this worked you can run this command `composer dumpautoload` and after that try `php artisan route:list` it will definitely work .